# Add formula to Pivot Chart Title Using Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code that creates a pivot chart with a variable title based on the filter criteria chosen.

I am having trouble typing a formula into the .charttitle.characters.text format and having it auto update when a new filter is chosen in the pivot table.

Here is my code.  As you can see, I am trying to relate the Chart title back to a cell that formulates based off of the pivot table.  If there an easier way to code this, please let me know.

The Pivot Table filter is located in Sheet("Database Pivot").Range("B1") if that wasn't particularly clear.

```
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SA Pivot Table")
Set objPivRange = objTable.TableRange1

Sheets("SA").Range("Z1").Formula = "=IF('Database Pivot'!$B$1=""(All)"", ""Since "" & TEXT('Database'!$L$2,""MM/DD/YYYY""), IF('Database Pivot'!$B$1=""(Multiple Items)"", ""For Selected Dates"", ""On "" & TEXT('Database Pivot'!$B$1,""MM/DD/YYYY"")))"


Set objChart = Charts.Add
With objChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "=""Average WC Adherence "" & 'SA'!$Z$1"
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .Location xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Adherence Chart"
    .PlotBy = xlColumns
    .SetSourceData objPivRange
    With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "% Adherence"
    End With
    With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Work Center"
        .TickLabels.Orientation = 90
        .TickLabels.Font.Size = 7.5
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but it appears that certain formulas and operators cannot be used in the formula of a dynamic Chart table. We know that a simple, single cell reference in a formula will work, like `"='SA'!$Z$1"`.

Therefore, your best option would be to create the dynamic chart title in another cell, and then have the formula in your chart title reference the single cell containing your dynamic chart title. Below the line where you set the formula of cell Z1, add the following line

```
' I use Z2, use whatever cell you see fit
Sheets("SA").Range("Z2") = "Average WC Adherence " & Sheets("SA").Range("Z1")
```

Then update the chart title formula to reference cell

```
.ChartTitle.Caption = "='SA'!$Z$2"
```

Noticed I also changed `.Characters.Text` to `.Caption`, since the Caption property can detect if it should contain text or a formula

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but it seems as though the issue isn't with the text being added in the title, but rather the cell reference.  Using `.ChartTitle.Characters.Text` seems to warrant the vba code to pass over any cell reference as text.  The chart title just appears as ='SA'!$AA$1 instead of referencing the cell.  Is there any other way to put a chart title in, such as `.ChartTitle.Formula`?

Comment: When I tested it, I was using the `ChartObject` object not realizing you were using the `Chart` object. I'll update.

Comment: The `.ChartTitle.Caption` fixed everything! Thank you!